# Toggling picture display using a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

So, I am trying to write some code that, when you check the checkbox, it stops displaying the pictures on my website. I am getting no syntax errors in my text software nor in the console. Could any one tell me what the problem is with this code?

```
function Checkbox(element){
    var pic=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
if(element.checked==true){
    for(var i=0; i<pic.length; i++){
        pic[i].style.display="none";
    }
}
else if(element.checked==false){ 
     for(var i=0; i<pic.length; i++){
        pic[i].style.display="auto";
    }
}}; 
//picDisplay is the id of my checkbox
var picDisplay=document.getElementById("picDisplay");
picDisplay.addEventListener("click",Checkbox(picDisplay)
```

Comment: the second ")" for the event listener is present in my actual code.

Comment: Can you share full code

Comment: what is `picDisplay`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yLb1xteu/

The main problem in your code is that you need to pass in a function pointer to the `Checkbox` function in `picDisplay.addEventListener`.  Instead, you are running the `Checkbox` function and passing the result (basically nothing) to `addEventListener`, which doesn't do much.

Also naming a function `Checkbox` isn't the best - just throwing that out there.  Might want to name it something like `togglePictures`.  :)

Have fun coding!

Comment: this fixed my problem :). I thought that only on the event "click" that the function Checkbox would be run with the parameter "picDisplay", but I realize it was just trying to run the result of the function Checkbox which, like you said, is basically nothing. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a sample of what you are looking for.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="picDisplay" onchange="Checkbox()"
>

<div style="width:10%;">
<img src="http://www.ricoh-imaging.co.jp/english/r_dc/caplio/r7/img/sample_04.jpg" style="width:100%;">
</div>
<script>
function Checkbox(){
var Checkbox_value = document.getElementById("picDisplay");
    var pic=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
if(Checkbox_value.checked==true){
    for(var i=0; i<pic.length; i++){
        pic[i].style.display="none";
    }
}
else if(Checkbox_value.checked==false){ 
     for(var i=0; i<pic.length; i++){
        pic[i].style.display="block";
    }
}}; 
</script>

Try the code given above and think this is helpful
```